# Connect a line between two ellipses

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to connect a line between two ellipses where if one was dragged the line would move with it. I have a canvas and inside that are two stackpanels... in each stackpanel is an ellipse on the left... content control in the middle... and another ellipse on the right. The idea is to connect a line between the right ellipse from one stackpanel to the left ellipse in the second stackpanel. So far I have this but can't seem to get much farther as the propertypath being used to do the binding doesn't make too much sense to me... which is why I have a Canvas in there right now.

```
Line line = new Line();
line.Stroke = connectedEllipse.Fill;
line.StrokeThickness = 2;

Binding x1 = new Binding();
Binding x2 = new Binding();
Binding y1 = new Binding();
Binding y2 = new Binding();

x1.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty);
x2.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty);
y1.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty);
y2.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty);

x1.Source = y1.Source = connectedEllipse;
x2.Source = y2.Source = (sender as Ellipse);

line.SetBinding(Line.X1Property, x1);
line.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, x2);
line.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, y1);
line.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, y2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've hacked up some code which doesn't use the attached properties method. This probably isn't "good" code since I wrote it up in 20 minutes but it will get you started.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EllipseTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:EllipseTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="template1">
            <Ellipse Width="60" Height="30" Fill="Blue" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas Name="canvas">
        <my:ExtendedThumb x:Name="thumb1" Canvas.Left ="0" Canvas.Top="0" DragDelta="myThumb_DragDelta" Template="{StaticResource template1}" />
        <my:ExtendedThumb x:Name="thumb2" Canvas.Left ="50" Canvas.Top="20" DragDelta="myThumb_DragDelta" Template="{StaticResource template1}" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace EllipseTest
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      Path path;

      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void myThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
      {
         ExtendedThumb thumb = e.Source as ExtendedThumb;
         Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
         Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
         if (thumb == thumb1)
            UpdateLine(thumb, thumb2);
         else
            UpdateLine(thumb1, thumb);
      }

      private void UpdateLine(ExtendedThumb firstThumb, ExtendedThumb secondThumb)
      {
         double left1 = Canvas.GetLeft(firstThumb);
         double top1 = Canvas.GetTop(firstThumb);

         double left2 = Canvas.GetLeft(secondThumb);
         double top2 = Canvas.GetTop(secondThumb);

         thumb1.ConnectingLine.StartPoint = new Point(left1 +firstThumb.ActualWidth / 2, top1 + firstThumb.ActualHeight / 2);
         thumb1.ConnectingLine.EndPoint = new Point(left2 + secondThumb.ActualWidth / 2, top2 + secondThumb.ActualHeight / 2);

         thumb2.ConnectingLine.StartPoint = new Point(left2 + secondThumb.ActualWidth / 2, top2 + secondThumb.ActualHeight / 2);
         thumb2.ConnectingLine.EndPoint = new Point(left1 + firstThumb.ActualWidth / 2, top1 + firstThumb.ActualHeight / 2);

      }

      private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         path = new Path();
         path.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
         path.StrokeThickness = 2;

         canvas.Children.Add(path);

         LineGeometry line = new LineGeometry();
         path.Data = line;

         thumb1.ConnectingLine = line;
         thumb2.ConnectingLine = line;

         UpdateLine(thumb1, thumb2);

      }
   }
}
```

ExtendedThumb.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EllipseTest
{
   public class ExtendedThumb : Thumb
   {
      public LineGeometry ConnectingLine { get; set; }

      public ExtendedThumb() : base() { ConnectingLine = new LineGeometry(); }
   }
}
```

Also, I got the idea from the contents of this link: http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/wpf-draggable-objects-and-simple-shape-connectors/

Comment: Hmm... looking at attached properties but can't find one that makes sense.

Comment: So you would create an attached property, call it something like `PointInEllipse`. Now in your code behind where you are setting the binding, do some math and find a point which is inside your ellipse (maybe the center) and then bind the `X1Property` of the line to that point. Do the same for the second ellipse and bind `X2Property` to that. Here is an article about binding to attached properties. http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/15/binding-to-an-attached-property.aspx Does that seem to make sense?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do this... I have not worked with binding in code behind before. The example you gave isn't hinting at how to go about doing this. But it does sound like its the right way to go.

Comment: Another thought... what if I place each Ellipse into its own Canvas... would I then be able to set the line to connect the ellipse outside the canvas, outside the stackpanel.. onto the intial canvas, and then back into the other stackpanel containing a canvas and then the ellipse?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but from what I do understand, I don't see the advantage in it.

Comment: Scratch that, the code I posted probably won't work. I'll think about this a little more and get back to you.

Comment: Hmm... what you mentioned does make sense, unsure how the binding is suppose to know that the helper class is for the ellipse... but I'll continue to experiment while you think of another way. I remember doing this in Windows Forms and it was a great deal easier. Too bad there is no simple way of doing this even without a binding.

Comment: I've posted some more code that appears to work. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This doesn't look like it will work with stackpanels in between the canvas and the ellipse... when looking at Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top... the element is not directly inside the canvas.

Comment: You mean that the Ellipse is inside a stackpanel? Well if you add a StackPanel to the control template of Thumb then it will work. You're moving the Thumb, not the Ellipse.

Comment: Another idea might be to use Adorners. An adorner exists in a layer seperate from that of the controls it adorns so it will render regardless of whether your controls are in the same or seperate panels.

Comment: I'm playing around with your sample... if i can get canvas.left and canvas.top to get through to the ellipse based on where the stackpanel is this might work

Comment: This was the way to go... not exactly the same routine however the same principle applies, doing it manually and adjusting the line when the item is moved. Thanks Tejas!